# Why are uv faces always distorted?

Tags: uv

Why are uv faces always distorted? I even tried to delete all modifiers and shape keys, but it's still red. Even if I try to unwrap one single face, still red. I want to create map via texture painting. And this oddness in uv unwrapping confuse me. Please, tell where I made mistake.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of UV unwrapping is to project a curved model into a plain (in which you will paint the texture), so a quad in your model will always result in a different (distorted) quad in the texturing canvas. A lot of UV options are available to try to let the UV unwrapping being "readable": for instance you can set the front view and then select "project from view": the result will be "what you see is what you get", but - obiouvsly  - the faces you don't see (the lateral ones expecially) will be heavily distorted.

The tipical workflow for unvrapping a human head is:

- modelling the mesh trying to have all quads nearly in a real quad shape (not rectangular) and nearly of the same dimensions
- mark some edges as "seams", to divide the head into smaller parts which can allow seams in the texture and which will minimize the stretch of the various parts

If your are unfamiliar with theese concepts I suggest you to start unwrapping simpler models, to get used to the procedure

[image]